# How to add a macro with clBuildProgram for OpenCL

Tags: opencl

In my kernel i have this defined.

```
#define ACTIVATION_FUNCTION(X) (1.7159f*tanh(2.0f/3.0f*X))
```

I would like to define it in the clBuildProgram call, such i can alter the kernel at runtime. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-D` argument to the OpenCL compiler, by passing it in the `options` parameter of the `clBuildProgram` function. Passing `-D x=y`, is equivalent to adding `#define x y` at the top of your kernel file. Similarly, passing `-D x` is equivalent to adding `#define x` (for any `x` and `y`, of course).

In your case, you probably want to pass something like this:

```
-D ACTIVATION_FUNCTION(X)=(1.7159f*tanh(2.0f/3.0f*X))
```

Which you can then change as you see fit, directly from your program, at runtime.

Note you could also open the kernel file and write the define directly into it, as an alternative solution, but this is probably the cleanest way. Just be careful with newlines, I'm not sure how well they are handled.

---

Ref. [this documentation page on clBuildProgram](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html), "Preprocessor Options" section.

Comment: Thanks, doh, i tried -A NAME = (X)(....X...). Alteast i was on the right track. thanks.